# How to solve error 504: Gateway Timeout between Angular and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'm making an application where I run my frontend in angular and my backend in asp.net.

In asp.net I have a RecipeApi which provides recipes to the frontend part in Angular. Running this code in Swagger works. All the code from Angular is running correctly, but when I use Angular to get data from the RecipeApi I always get the same error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Timeout).

All this is running on my localhost.

I already tried to disable my firewall while running these applications and I added the SSL certificate. I changed the name of localhost to [::1] in my proxy.conf.json file, but I don't really know where else I have to look to fix this error.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, RecipeDataInitializer recipeDataInitializer)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSwaggerUi3();
            app.UseSwagger();

            recipeDataInitializer.InitializeData(); //.Wait();
        }
```

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "port": 44393
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```